# WCF or simple library class for my ASP.NET MVC application and performance issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, iis, n-tier-architecture

I am working in my Application Architecture and i am wondering if i should use WCF or not.
The UI will be a public website written in ASP.NET MVC 3 but in the future possible Iphone/Android applications...
So now i have a data layer (Entity framework + repository), business layer (Class library) 
and UI (ASP.NET MVC) communicating via ViewModel.

I understand that in a good SOA application the business layer should be exposed as a webservice but i am wondering about performance issues, beacause my website traffic will be high and hosting the WCF and the website in IIS in the same machine is a waste of time and of performance since to communicate they have to serialize/deserialize objects.

Is keeping my business layer in a dll (class library) and deploy it in the ASP.NET application better then hoting it in a wcf service ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/06/13/premature-optimization-and-performance-anxiety.aspx

I think that leaving things as just a dll for right now would be the simplest solution until you firm up your requirements for iphone/android solutions. We use WCF extensively where I work, and it can be very fast.

That said, creating a WCF service on the chance you might need it later seems premature and its always easy to add a web reference later and remove the dll. You can't get the hours spent on a WCF service back (and the risk of needlessly adding another layer between your app and its data) as easily.

Comment: thank you for your answer. any idea about performance difference between the solution with the dll in the asp.net and the asp.net calling the wcf in the same server ?

Comment: Well, if you ask me, if you are hitting the database in both instances, that's probably the slowest part of the whole deal. Messaging on the same server can be pretty quick if you use something like Net.Pipes for the items that share the server. Then, in the future, you could expose other endpoints to systems that need to communicate remotely (say, over http).

Comment: I am agree with Killnine. You should stay with DLLs unless you have confirmed necessity to implement second GUI. Think also about efforts for WCF implementation and maintenance. It is very possible that mobile device will implement only limited functionality so time you spent on services for functions not exposed in mobile will be wasted.